node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'. for angular-in-memory-web-api "^0.18.0"
I follow the tutorial in https://v8.angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6, when I run npm start, many error come from node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/index.d.ts, like follows:

ERROR in node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/index.d.ts:38:19 -
error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
38     protected get dbReady(): Observable;
~~~~~~~ node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/index.d.ts:264:21 - error
TS2694: Namespace
'"{path}/angular-tour-of-heroes/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has
no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.
264     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<HttpClientBackendService,
[null, { optional: true; }, null]>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/index.d.ts:265:22 - error
TS2694: Namespace
'"{path}/angular-tour-of-heroes/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has
no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'.
265     static ɵprov:
i0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/index.d.ts:297:21 - error
TS2694: Namespace
'"{path}/angular-tour-of-heroes/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has
no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.
297     static ɵfac:
i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule, never>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/index.d.ts:298:21 - error
TS2694: Namespace
'"{path}/angular-tour-of-heroes/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has
no exported member 'ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration'.
298     static ɵmod:
i0.ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration<HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule, never, never,
never>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/index.d.ts:299:21 - error
TS2694: Namespace
'"{path}/angular-tour-of-heroes/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has
no exported member 'ɵɵInjectorDeclaration'.
299     static ɵinj:
i0.ɵɵInjectorDeclaration;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/index.d.ts:312:21 - error
TS2694: Namespace
'"{path}/angular-tour-of-heroes/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has
no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.
312     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<InMemoryBackendConfig,
never>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/index.d.ts:313:22 - error
TS2694: Namespace
'"{path}/angular-tour-of-heroes/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has
no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'.
313     static ɵprov:
i0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/index.d.ts:428:21 - error
TS2694: Namespace
'"{path}/angular-tour-of-heroes/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has
no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.
428     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<InMemoryWebApiModule,
never>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/index.d.ts:429:21 - error
TS2694: Namespace
'"{path}/angular-tour-of-heroes/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has
no exported member 'ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration'.
429     static ɵmod: i0.ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration<InMemoryWebApiModule,
never, never, never>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/index.d.ts:430:21 - error
TS2694: Namespace
'"{path}/angular-tour-of-heroes/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has
no exported member 'ɵɵInjectorDeclaration'.
430     static ɵinj: i0.ɵɵInjectorDeclaration;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

the dependencies/devDependencies section of my package.json is as follow:
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.18.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.25",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.26",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }

how to fix these error?

ok, I change to
npm install angular-in-memory-web-api@0.9 --save
and the server can be start without error now.
